# How can I avoid spaces after moving a relatively positioned element?

Tags: html, css

I have an`<article>` element inside a `<div>` and `article` has a `position: relative;`.
I moved it up 95px (`bottom: 95px;`) but the space it took up in its original place remained there. How can I make that disappear? When I do the same with `article` positioned as absolute, there is no problem. But I need to stick this to the middle too and `margin: auto` won't work with `position:absolute`.

http://jsfiddle.net/xnvMD/2/

Comment: Although you did describe your problem, it is greatly appreciated to be able to see some code. Consider adding some code so that your question will have a much higher value. From what you have described, try giving `div` stylings of `position:absolute`

Comment: Show us something visual.

Comment: jsfiddle example please?

Comment: You should use a negative top margin. And get rid of the relative position.

Comment: Negative top margin won't help it makes the triangle disappear: http://jsfiddle.net/xnvMD/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an`<article>` element inside a `<div>` and `article` has a `position: relative;`.
>   I moved it up 95px (`bottom: 95px;`) but the space it took up in its original place remained there.

Well, this is how relative positioning is *supposed* to work – http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position:

> *“When a box B is relatively positioned, the position of the following box is calculated as though B were not offset.”*

So the *original* space required by a relatively positioned element gets reserverd.

> How can I make that disappear? When I do the same with `article` positioned as absolute, there is no problem. But I need to stick this to the middle too and `margin: auto` won't work with `position:absolute`.

Have you tried just using a negative `margin-top` to “move” the element upwards? This should work in all browsers (that are not from the stone age). And you can still set the horizontal margins to `auto` to have your element centered.

```
.trdown {
  /* everything else besides position and bottom stays */
  margin:-85px auto 0 auto;
}
```

(If this destroys the spacing at the bottom of the container element that you want to keep, then give that a `padding-bottom` as well.)

Comment: That’s not a problem with the negative margin itself – it’s because `z-index` does only work for positioned elements (that means, `position` has a value other then the default `static`. So keep `position:relative` in as well, just without the `bottom` value: http://jsfiddle.net/xnvMD/4/

Comment: And btw., I see it all the time – but there is usually no need for _exorbitantly high_ z-index values (most developers I know set them high only because they have not fully understand how z-index works) – `z-index:1` is absolutely enough here (at least in this simple example), see http://jsfiddle.net/xnvMD/5/ Once on that path, the problem keeps multiplying if your are using several positioned elements with different z-indexes – “so I used `2000` on that element before, so for the next one I’ll need at least `2001`, but I’ll make it `3000` instead, just to be sure” … don’t do it, it’s bad.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the relative position, use a negative top margin. Something like this:

```
margin:-95px auto 0 auto;
```

As CBroe has already pointed out, to get the arrow to show up over the image above, you'll need to add back the `position:relative` (but not the `bottom`) when you set the `z-index`.

```
position:relative;
z-index:1;
```

Technically you don't even need the `z-index`.

If you're curious why this works the way it does, you need to understand the rules for painting order in CSS. The [full details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html) are fairly complicated, but the basics are outlined in [the section on the z-index property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index).

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

By default, images (which classify as inline-level, non-positioned descendants) are at level 5, which is above your `article` element (a non-inline-level descendant) at level 3.

By adding a `postion:relative` to the `article` element, you've made it a positioned descendant, level 6, and thus moved it higher up the stack and above the image again.

Note that if your `article` had contained any inline content of its own, that would have displayed above the `img` element (they're both inline, but the article's inline content comes later in the tree order), but the `article` background and borders would still have painted below.

Comment: If I use this, the triangle disappears, tried z-index, did not help: http://jsfiddle.net/xnvMD/3/

Comment: I see that CBroe has already answered you, but I've updated my answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to add a comment without first adding an answer. Without seeing code like Cody added it's difficult to help.

I think you're not entirely sure how positioning works. When an element is set to position: absolute, it's then positioned in relation to the first parent element it has that doesn't have position: static. If there's no such element, the element with position: absolute gets positioned relative to `<html>` (from Codecademy)

If you give an element relative positioning and tell it to have a margin-top of 10px, it doesn't move down ten pixels from any particular thing—it moves down ten pixels from where it otherwise would have been.

Remember, that if your using margin-auto on an element inside of another element, it will center inside of that element, as opposed to the document. Div's by default are the entire width of the page though.